# Snowflake orchestration of tasks

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a batch load process that loads data into a staging database. I have a number of tasks that execute stored procedures which move the data to a different database. The tasks are executed when the SYSTEM$STREAM_HAS_DATA condition is satisfied on a given table.

I have a separate stored procedure that I want to execute only after the tasks have completed moving the data.

However, I have no way to know which tables will receive data and therefore do not know which tasks will be executed.

How can I know when all the tasks that satisfied the SYSTEM$STREAM_HAS_DATA condition are finished and I can now kick off the other stored procedure? Is there a way to orchestrate this step by step process similar to how you would in a SQL job?

Answer (score 1):

There is no automated way but you can do it with some coding.

You may create a stored procedure to check the STATE column of the task_history view to see if the tasks are completed or skipped:

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/task_history.html

You can call this stored procedure periodically using a task (like every 5 minutes etc).

Based on your checks inside of the stored procedure (*all tasks were succeeded, the target SP wasn't executed today yet etc*), you can execute your target stored procedure which needs to be executed after all tasks have been completed.

Answer (score 1):

You can also check the status of all the streams via SELECT SYSTEM$STREAM_HAS_DATA('<stream_name>') FROM STREAM which does not process the stream, or SELECT COUNT(*) FROM STREAM.
Look into using IDENTIFIER for dynamic queries.